# Sqlite on Android handling of NaN value

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to establish if I have found a bug in sqlite or if it is just with my understanding (as I haven't had a lot of experience with it).
(And, yes I have checked the sqlite bug tracker.)

I have an Android where I want to store doubles in the database. I also want store a record where the value may not be set yet (ie invalid). To track this state I want to store Double.NaN.

So when I create the database table as such

```
create table Example (myRecordId integer primary key autoincrement, someString text not null, problemDouble REAL);
```

Insert a record where the problemDouble is Double.NaN and then access via Cursor.getDouble(...) I will get back a Java double with the value 0.0.

Now if I create the table this way (using text instead of real)

```
create table Example (myRecordId integer primary key autoincrement, someString text not null, problemDouble text);
```

Insert the record where the Java double is converted to a string and access it the same way I will get back a double with the value NaN.

I thought that that sqlite is supposed to be typeless but it appears to be messing around with the value when the column is a REAL. Or is it that sql REAL don't support a NaN value?

My assumption would be that sqlite is just converting the REAL values to strings in the background.

So would this inconsistency be considered a bug ?